# Rails: How much is model destruction automated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this kind of setup:

```
:procedures, has_many => :steps
```

Steps are tied to the procedures that they were created under. Currently my method destroy for Procedures is just this:

```
def destroy
    @procedure.destroy
end
```

Is it necessary to go find all the steps associated with this procedure and invoke their destroy methods, or will Rails handle this for me automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the dependent sub-items included in the destroy by using the ':dependent => :destroy' option.

So in your case it'd be:

```
has_many => :steps, :dependent => :destroy
```

Which will destroy steps when the procedure is destroyed.

You could also use:

```
has_many => :steps, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Which from the rails site

> The :destroy and :delete_all option
>   symbols are so named because they
>   correspond with the behavior achieved
>   by calling destroy versus delete on a
>   model object. One triggers callbacks,
>   the other just generates the delete
>   SQL statement

So the delete_all won't trigger destroy callbacks and destroy will.

Comment: How would I add the :dependent option if I used block notation? I added in my code sample to the question.